# Accessing array at index 0 returns correctly, but accessing at index 1+ generates error?

Tags: java, arrays

Here is the code:

```
System.out.println("[Server] Handshake Recieved");

String fdata = new String(p.getData());
String[] data = fdata.split(";");

System.out.println(fdata);
System.out.println(data.length);
System.out.println(data[0]);
```

p is the name of a Packet class I made. getData() returns a byte array that I can confirm always returns correctly.

When this code runs with data[0], this is the console output:

```
CID;0;Username;Dummy
4
CID
```

But when I run it with data[1], this is what happens:

```
<blank>
1
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at server.S_GameLoop.parseData(S_GameLoop.java:122)
    at server.S_GameLoop.Update(S_GameLoop.java:87)
    at server.S_GameLoop.Running(S_GameLoop.java:66)
    at server.S_GameLoop.run(S_GameLoop.java:157)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

I have no clue why this is happening. Perhaps one of you knows the answer?

Edit:
Here's the functions that contains the problematic code:

```
private void parseData(Packet p, DatagramPacket recievePacket) throws IOException, MethodNotOverridenException {
    switch (p.getTagAsString()) {
    case "LGN_RQS":
        System.out.println("[Server] Login Request Recieved");
        //Login was accepted
        //Create a Client ref, and add it to the vector
        S_Client newClient = new S_Client(recievePacket.getAddress(), recievePacket.getPort());
        ClientList.add(newClient);

        //Create a player and add it to Entity list
        Player newPlayer = new Player(IDGenerator.getAndIncrement(), ClientList.indexOf(newClient));
        EntityMap.put(newPlayer.getEntID(), newPlayer);
        System.out.println("[Server] Created new Player with EID " + newPlayer.getEntID() + " and CID " + newPlayer.getCID());
        //Send reply to Client that is logging in
        sendData(new Packet((byte)2, "LGN_ACP".toCharArray(), ("CID;" + ClientList.indexOf(newClient) + ";EID;" + newPlayer.getEntID()).getBytes()).getBytes(), newClient.getIp(), newClient.getPort());
        //New Entity was created
        sendData(newPlayer.onCreate(this));
    case "HND_SHK":
        System.out.println("[Server] Handshake Recieved");

        String fdata = new String(p.getData());
        String[] data = fdata.split(";");

        System.out.println(p.getData()); //[B@170ad4d5
        System.out.println(fdata);
        System.out.println(data.length);
        System.out.println(data[0]);

        /*S_Client c = ClientList.get(Integer.parseInt(data[1]));
        c.setUsername(data[3]);
        System.out.println("[Server] Set Client " + data[1] + "'s user to " + data[3]); */
    }
}
```

Here's Packet.java:

```
public class Packet {
private byte ID;
private char[] Tag;
private byte[] Data;

public Packet(byte ID, char Tag[]) {
    this.ID = ID;
    if(Tag.length <= 7)
        this.Tag = Tag;
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tag must be at most 7 characters long");
    this.Data = new byte[1];
}

public Packet(byte ID, char Tag[], byte[] Data) {
    this.ID = ID;
    if(Tag.length <= 7)
        this.Tag = Tag;
    else
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Tag must be at most 7 characters long");
    this.Data = Data;
}

/*
 * Returns the packet ID
 */
public byte getID() {
    return ID;
}

/*
 * Return's the packet TAG
 */
public char[] getTag() {
    return Tag;
}

public String getTagAsString() {
    return new String(Tag);
}

public byte[] getData() {
    return Data;
}

public byte[] getBytes() {
    byte[] c = {ID};
    return concat(c, concat(new String(Tag).getBytes(), Data));
}

public byte[] concat(byte[] A, byte[] B) {
       int aLen = A.length;
       int bLen = B.length;
       byte[] C= new byte[aLen+bLen];
       System.arraycopy(A, 0, C, 0, aLen);
       System.arraycopy(B, 0, C, aLen, bLen);
       return C;
}
```

}

**Second Edit**:

Bit of clarifications. I run the program twice. Once with data[0] and once with data[1]. Each time I run it. They both produce the exact same individual results. data[0] will always return

```
CID;0;Username;Dummy
4
CID
```

Which is correct. But swapping out data[0] with data[1] will always return

```
**<blank>
1**
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at server.S_GameLoop.parseData(S_GameLoop.java:122)
    at server.S_GameLoop.Update(S_GameLoop.java:87)
    at server.S_GameLoop.Running(S_GameLoop.java:66)
    at server.S_GameLoop.run(S_GameLoop.java:157)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

**Final Edit**
If someone somehow comes across this question. The problem turned out to be me forgeting to add `break;` in my switch statements.

Comment: whats happening is, there is nothing at `data[1]`

Comment: You aren't even giving any input when you are using `date[1]`.

Comment: Please provide a *complete*, short example which illustrates your problem. The code you have given shouldn't cause the error you have described with the example input you show. I think the problem might be somewhere else in your code. In particular, what is `p` and what is `getData()`?

Comment: I'm not seeing where the error is.  can you make a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that we can copy and paste so that we can observe the error ourselves?

Comment: Agree with @Code-Guru. The two scenarios are totally different. Changing an index doesn't change the length of an array. I think your last sample gets a packet with the wrong data.

Comment: @Bart the it shouldn't get the wrong data ALL the time. Especially since there are other sections of code that do something similar and work all the time.

Comment: @ILikePizza555 But it obviously does :-)

Comment: Your question makes it sound like you simply replace `data[0]` with `data[1]`. It also doesn't make it clear that you have different inputs with each one. Please correct this and I will gladly reverse my downvote.

Comment: @Code-Guru I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. I do replace data[0] with data[1], and both are supposed to contain different values. The issue is that if I access data[0] everything prints out correctly, but If I access data[1], not even the original string prints our correctly. The result is always the same for both of them, which is why I don't think the packet is invalid.

Comment: Then the repeated code occurs somewhere else because the input is different for your two examples. Please provide a *complete* code example which we can copy and paste to recreate the exact same error which you see.

Comment: @Code-Guru it's a rather big project, but I could link to you to the Github page. I'll do that now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at your second log output very carefully. On that second run of the program, the fdata String is empty, hence log line one is `<blank>`. When you tokenize a blank string with ';', you get back one token, also an empty string. Thus line 2 of your log is 1 (the token array has 1 element in it). Then you try to index the token array at index 1 (which accesses the SECOND element of the array); there's only an element at index 0, because the array has length 1. So as the exception says, your index is out of bounds.

It looks like the real bug in your program is p.getData() is returning an empty string sometimes. This would indicate that your logic to "confirm [the packet] always returns correctly" has a bug in it.

Comment: If I get an invalid packet, then why is it that everytime I run it with data[1] I get the same error, yet, everytime I run the same code with data[0], I get the exact same response: The string being correct, array.length returning correctly, and data[0] returning the right value.

Comment: Post the rest of the code and we might be able to find out for you. Please notice how all the upvoted answers have exactly the same explanation.

Comment: okay, I added a link to my project, along with some clarification. I still don't see how it can be a bad packet.

Comment: Well, I managed to figure out the problem.

Turns out it was a "bad packet". In the switch statement, I forgot to add "break;"

Answer (score 2):

It is pretty obvious. Your different tests do use different data, received from `p.getData()`.

At the first test, your method `p.getData()` returns a good String to work on. The second test, you got an empty String (of size 0), which is not what you expected. So look beyond this code you provided, and search for the reason why `p.getData()` does return different things.

Comment: Nice job paraphrasing my answer.

Comment: Check out the times we submitted our answers. We posted it almost at the same moment :)

Comment: I saw your original unedited answer, after I'd already posted mine :)

Comment: Yes, that is the way stackoverflow works. You've got five minutes to make changed to it without being marked as changes. And to be honest, I didn't read your answer yet. I'll have a look and probably up vote, because you claim I wrote the same :P

Answer (score -1):

Your array has only one element, most likely because split drops the trailing empty strings (if any). `array[1]` tries to access the second element, which does not exist.

Comment: @Idles It's the OP's fault.  He wrote his question in such a way that people assume that he's using the same dataset for both cases

Comment: @Idles It's very easy to miss the `<blank>` and `1` above the stack trace, so people assume that he's just calling his `data[1]` immediately after `data[0]`